# async await from callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

I have this function which saves user in database:

```
exports.saveUser = ({ first_name, last_name, email, password }) => {
    const query = "insert into users (first_name, last_name, email, password_hash) values ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING *";
    bcrypt.hash(password, 10, async function (err, hash) {
        const res = await db.query(query, [first_name, last_name, email, hash]);
        return res.rows[0];
    });
    return res;
};
```

I have async function inside bcrypt callback where insertion is happening and where I'm returning inserted row. How do i make it to return for saveUser function?

So at the end `saveUser()` will be that `res.rows[0]` record?

Comment: saveUser() needs to be an async function so the caller can await it.

Comment: yeah. fixed that.

Comment: yes. posted it too.

Comment: "*I have async function inside bcrypt callback*" - don't do that. Get a promise for the result of the bcrypt call, wait for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
exports.saveUser = async ({ first_name, last_name, email, password }) => {
    const query = "insert into users (first_name, last_name, email, password_hash) values ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING *";
    let hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    const res = await db.query(query, [first_name, last_name, email, hash]);
    return res.rows[0];
};
```

i have made bcrypt.hash await instead of callback. then made saveUser async ad it worked

Comment: Could you add a description on how this answers the question? (+1)